# Polynomial rings over a commutative ring with identity

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Consider the polynomial ring in $n$ indeterminates $R[X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}]$. Let $R[Y_{1},\ldots ,Y_{m}]$ be a polynomial sub-ring of it in $m$ indeterminates. I want to prove that $m\leq n$.
So I'm given two facts here:

- $Y_{i},1\leq i \leq m$ can be written in terms of $X_{j},1\leq j\leq n$.
- $\{Y_{i}\}_{1\leq i \leq m}$ are algebraically independent over $R$.

Hints are most welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "in terms of"? Do you mean that the $Y_i$ are represented as polynomials. E.g. $Y_1 = X_1^2X_3 + 2$? Does that work? Are constants disallowed so $Y_1 = X_1X_2 + X_3^5$ is fine?

Comment: When you say that they are algebraically independent, do you mean that any linear combination with coefficients in $R$ that is zero has zero coefficients or do you allow coefficients to be in the polynomial ring? If not, then $X, X^2, X^3, \dots$ would be independent.

Comment: @user357980 Yes,$Y_{i}$ is represented as a polynomial in $R[X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}]$

Comment: @user357980 my mistake. I meant algebraically independent over $R$, which means $g[Y_{1},\ldots, Y_{m}]=0 \implies $ coefficients of $g$ are $0$.

Comment: I have a proof based on some successive reductions of $R$: noetherian, noetherian reduced, finite direct product of fields. I hope someone can provide a simpler or more direct proof.

Comment: @user26857 I'm having hard time proving even in the case when $R$ is a field. Care to explain a bit how to proceed?

Comment: The proof that crosses my mind is the following: if $K[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]\subset K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ then $K(Y_1,\dots,Y_m)\subset K(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and now use that the transcendence degree eventually increases in field extensions.

Comment: @user26857 I see